# Hobbyist microcontroller without code write endurance worry

Tags: microcontroller

I'm looking for a hobbyist microcontroller that can have its code modified very frequently (like code generated on the fly, or polymorphic code), without worrying about running out of write cycles. Meeting any one of these requirements will fulfill this:

- Uses a Von Neumann architecture, or
- Has the ability to use some of its RAM as code memory despite being Harvard architecture, or
- Can execute code from external memory/storage, or
- Has internal nonvolatile storage with no write cycle limit (e.g., [MRAM](https://www.everspin.com/toggle-mram-technology))

In addition, it should have both of these requirements:

- Supported by an open-source toolchain, and
- Usable without needing to surface-mount solder (i.e., either available in a DIP package or pre-mounted on a breakout/dev board)

Comment: Very uncommon request. I'm wondering: What's your motivation? Why this approach? What's the reason for this very uncommon approach?

Comment: Why do you need *infinite* write endurance instead of just *high* write endurance?

Comment: The only thing I know of with high but not infinite write endurance is ferroelectric RAM, and it has the large disadvantage that reads count against it too (since they're destructive). If you know of another technology with high write endurance, I'd probably be okay with it.

Comment: @JosephSible Would 3D XPoint like that used in Optane be acceptable? My only concern is that it's fairly large, expensive, and only comes on Intel's modules ATM–things that probably aren't desirable in a microcontroller application.